# How does the performance of an if statement compare to using an interface?

Tags: c#, java, if-statement, branch

When there is a change in an application state, the application loop (or game loop, whatever it's called) now has to execute a different set of instructions. Often times, this means using an if statement.

I have found that using interfaces and a interface reference variable can alleviate the need for if statements, and it makes the state changes look much nicer.

```
class red implements IColor
class blue implements IColor

IColor colorState;

Application loop
{
    colorState.drawColor
}
```

This is an example of what I mean by an interface removing the need for an if statement. Now when you want to change the state from red to blue, you just do

```
colorState = a reference to a blue instance;
```

But I wonder if an if statement that is as simple as this

```
if (bool)
    stuff
else
    stuff
```

Is worse than interface? I know normally if statements are supposed to be expensive, and branch predictors come into play, but is a branch even being predicted here?

Comment: I don't understand at what level you want your question answered. Branch prediction is not a function of the language.. yet you've produced language constructs throughout your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: That would be a branching point but I wouldn't worry about that unless you've profiled and found it to be a bottle neck. In the first instance write code that is clear

Comment: Also if statements are expensive compared to what?

Comment: @RichardTingle Interfaces. Would you like me to write an example of how an interface can replace an if statement?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you post the interface solution you mention?

Comment: @Szymon added interface solution

Comment: If statements are generally one of the least expensive constructs in any programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a typical implementation of the "State" pattern to an if statement. It does not matter what the boolean expression is, there will be at least one branching point. However, if the state changes infrequently, the branch will be correctly predicted most of the time.

However, efficiency is *not* among the top advantages of the "State" pattern: it offers a better readability to programmers familiar with the concept, and it also reduces your maintenance liabilities by keeping state-related changes close together. Most of the time, the potential inefficiency of a branch will be dwarfed by the CPU requirements of the actual "payload" work done by your state implementation.